# Generate multiple powerpoint files by updating chart

Tags: excel, vba

I need to generate multiple powerpoint files by updating chart in 2nd slide on excel data available in each row(dynamic row counts)

I have a excel file with around 1000 rows(count is dynamic every time) and each row is a record, based on 1 row i have created a chart in excel itself which i need to copy in second slide of my existing ppt template.  So in this way i need to generate 1000 ppts and save the files based on the name available in same row, can any one help me to resolve this query.

My logic is something like this.
Loop through all the rows
Create sheet
Create chart for first row
Copy paste in ppt fist slide
Then delete the chart or sheet in workbook
Repeat all the step till the end

Below is the code which i tried earlier where in i have created the chart in ppt and linked to the 1st row of my data file, but it only solves half of my problem that i can create only one report not multiple.

```
Sub Update()
Dim CName, pth
pth = ThisWorkbook.Path
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim Sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim sh As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim aLinks As Variant
Dim FName  As String
Dim strPptTemplatePath As String


strPptTemplatePath = "C:\Users\DSS1080\Desktop\Business continuity planning\Report Template.pptx"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = msoTrue
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(strPptTemplatePath, untitled:=msoTrue)
NewLink = pth & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
pptApp.Activate
For Each Sld In pptPres.Slides
    For Each sh In Sld.Shapes
    If sh.Type = msoChart Then
                 sh.Chart.ChartData.Activate
                 Set wb = sh.Chart.ChartData.Workbook
                 aLinks = wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
                    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(100, 100).Value = aLinks
                    Oldfile = Cells(100, 100).Value
                    wb.ChangeLink Name:=Oldfile, NewName:=NewLink, Type:=xlExcelLinks
                    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(100, 100).Clear
                wb.Close False
                 Set wb = Nothing
                 sh.Chart.ChartData.Activate
                 Set wb = sh.Chart.ChartData.Workbook
                 wb.Close False
                 Set wb = Nothing
    End If
Next
Next

FName = Sheets("Quadrant").Range("C1").Text
CName = Left(strPptTemplatePath, Len(strPptTemplatePath) - 19) & FName
pptPres.SaveAs CName, ppSaveAsDefault
pptPres.Close
Set pptPres = Nothing
pptApp.Quit
Set pptApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please add a screen shot of the excel data . Also, are you trying to create multiple ppt files and export the chart to the second slide of each file or are you trying to create one ppt file and start exporting charts from the secod file in the same file.